# Portainer / Docker-Compose execute "RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql"

Tags: linux, docker, docker-compose, portainer

I am trying to make Docker Container that hosts a Website that uses .php and mysql . I am using this docker-compose:

```
version: '3'
services:
  mariadb:
    image: mariadb:10.6
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: pw
      MYSQL_USER:  user
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: pw
    ports:
        - "9906:3306"
    volumes:
     - ./mariadb/db:/var/lib/mysql

  php:
    image: php:apache
    ports:
      - 8050:80
    volumes:
      - ./website/web:/var/www/html
```

When I try to use the Website it says couldnt find drivers. To solve this I have to put this command
"RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql" into a Dockerfile. But since I use docker-compose with Portainer I dont quite know how to make it run the command.

I tried to make envoriment variables or running it via console but that didnt work

Comment: Check database url that you use in your php app, it should be `mariadb:3306`. `localhost` is not going to work because for php container localhost means the container itself.

Comment: Yea im using mariadb:3306. But its still saying that :)